# elfutils compilation error implicit-function-declaration

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile

I downloaded elfutils 0.170 and 0.169, but can't use gcc to compile either of them because of implicit-function-declaration. I can't find any place in elfutils makefile which specifies -Werror or -Werror=implicit-function-declaration.  Any idea to fix this compilation error?

https://sourceware.org/elfutils/ftp/0.170/
My steps

1: bzip2 -d elfutils-0.170.tar.bz2
2: tar -xvf elfutils-0.170.tar
3: ./configure
4: make

Then below errors show up.
elf_compress_gnu.c: In function 'elf_compress_gnu':
elf_compress_gnu.c:114:28: error: implicit declaration of function 'htobe64' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
       uint64_t be64_size = htobe64 (orig_size);
                            ^
elf_compress_gnu.c:163:15: error: implicit declaration of function 'be64toh' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
       gsize = be64toh (gsize);
               ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors

Answer (score 2):

elfutils incorrectly uses `htobe64`, which is not in any standard and only available in glibc and a subset of the BSDs.

Since you use GCC, you can use Ulf Hermann's patch to work around this issue:

- [Add replacement endian.h and byteswap.h to libgnu](https://sourceware.org/ml/elfutils-devel/2017-q2/msg00147.html)

It adds an implementation of `htobe64` based on GCC built-in functions, so it is available when GCC is used as the compiler, independently of what the C library provides.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't want to patch and change libgnu. There was a elfutils-portabiliy.patch for elfutils to solve this issue but this patch had disappeared since 0.164 version. Any idea to fix this compilation error? And I can't send email to elfutils-devel@sourceware.org. Where should I send email to ask question on elfutils?

Comment: You either need to apply something like this patch or compile on Linux or one of the supported BSDs.